# Matlab figures in LaTeX, XTickLabel

Tags: matlab, latex

I want to include my figure in LaTeX document but have following problems.

1. Printing figure as EPS is not working. Figure is wrongly cropped. Please see figure below.
2. How to print multiple figures in a loop using handle?

My data:

```
str=[...
    '15.12.2012 11:27'
    '15.12.2012 11:12'
    '15.12.2012 10:57'
    '15.12.2012 10:42'
    '14.12.2012 10:27'
    '14.12.2012 10:12'
    '14.12.2012 09:57'
    '14.12.2012 09:42'
    '14.12.2012 09:27'
    '14.12.2012 09:12'
    '14.12.2012 08:57'
    '13.12.2012 08:42'
    '13.12.2012 08:27'
    '13.12.2012 08:12'
    '13.12.2012 07:57'
    '13.12.2012 07:42'
    '13.12.2012 07:27'
    '12.12.2012 07:12'
    '12.12.2012 06:57'
    '12.12.2012 06:42'
    '12.12.2012 06:27'
    '12.12.2012 06:12'
    '11.12.2012 05:57'
    '11.12.2012 05:42'
    '10.12.2012 05:27'
    '10.12.2012 05:12'
    '10.12.2012 04:57'];

Col1=[...
0.9884753
1.670642
1.14455
1.0301446
0.99031037
1.0459388
0.97192177
0.8925
0.8985693
0.955
0.95103529
0.95203444
0.955
0.95970876
0.95929422
0.95578656
0.955
0.955
0.95342687
0.955
0.955
0.95930485
0.95530825
0.96452381
0.9675
0.98778061
1.3];
Col2=rand(27,1).*(Col1);
Col3=Col1+Col2;
% find first occurrence of dates
[y,m,d,h,mn] = datevec(str,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM');

dn = datenum(y,m,d);
[~,ind] = unique(dn,'first');
ind = sort(ind);
% plot it nicely
plot(Col1);
hold all
plot(Col2);
hold all
plot(Col3);
leg_h=legend('bus','Car', 'truck','Location','NorthEastOutside');
set(leg_h,'Interpreter','latex','fontsize',14)
xlabel('time $t$','Interpreter','latex','fontsize',12);
ylabel('speed $m$','Interpreter','latex','fontsize',12);
ax = gca;
dstr = cellstr(datestr(dn,'dd.mm.yyyy'));
set(ax, 'XTick',ind, 'XTickLabel',dstr(ind), 'Position',[0.1,0.15,0.8,0.75]);
ylim([-20 20]); 


% plot something...
print -deps epsFig
```

The LaTeX code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, angle=0]{epsFig.eps}
\caption{Insert caption}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly better suited for [TeX.StackExchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The problem is likely to be an outlier in your data, so matlab compresses the `y` range. The axis labels are correct size, that rules out problems on TeX side.

Comment: @ user1666959 there is no outlier but I fixed ylim.It sould be fixed.

Comment: How do you create the .eps? try saving as and change the type to .eps

Comment: @ Tal Darom no change. I tried already (jpg, png, eps)

Comment: have you tried opening the eps in a viewer? does it look ok there, and wrongly cropped only in LaTeX?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think Latex automatically converts .eps files to .pdf before it can actually use them in the document. I'd check @TalDarom's suggestion and see if the cropping problem is a result of the eps -> pdf conversion.

Comment: @ Tal Darom, @ dinkelk I checked again with eps viewer. problem remains same.

Comment: @dinkelk you are wrong. It only does so if you use the epstopdf package and pdflatex to compile the document.

Comment: @user31177, so your problem is a problem in exporting the figure from matlab, and not a LaTeX issue. Try removing the legend, or moving it to the bottom of the figure.

Comment: @Tal Darom you r write. if I maximize my image befor saving or printing then, I don't have crop problem but on the other hand I get very dim(colors are not good) image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html). With 'keepticks', I find it works significantly better for date-time plots. Regardless, this is Matlab side, not Latex side.
2. I've started using [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) with great success.
3. Create a figure with (not sure why the code section isn't working)

   handle=figure;

   .. generate plot ..

   export_fig(handle, .... )